# AdminUI relationship field doesn't load full list of items

Tags: keystonejs

I have an `Article` object with a field called `country`:

`country: { type: Types.Relationship, ref: 'Country', initial: true }`

Country is a list in the database of all countries in the world (around 250 items in total).

When editing this field in an Article the dropdown only has the first 50 countries in it (and does not get updated when searching), for example if I search for "South Africa" this country is not available in the list. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix: I downgraded from version 0.3.22 which is the latest version on NPM, to 0.3.19 which is the latest version on GitHub. I'm not sure how it's possible to have version 0.3.22 on NPM because it doesn't even exist on GitHub... Very weird.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is by design, the limit is 50. The only way I could find is modifying the keystone/admin/api/list.js, line 27 (this is for the 0.3.22):

`var limit = req.query.limit || 50;`

Change the value of 50 to your desired value. Its not very elegant but it seems to be the only way at the moment.
You can find more info [here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/issues/1129).
Hope this helps